# Importing and Packages

Tags: java, package

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong, here. I have two files in a directory, let's call them FileA.java and FileB.java.

FileA.java has a definition along the lines of:

```
package com.domain.package;

import stuff;
import package.FileB;

public class FileA extends Blah implements Listener {
    /* global vars */
    /* methods */
}
```

FileB.java is my data object class, which I'd like to reference from FileA.java thusly:

```
Map<Object, FileB> varname;
```

to be used along the lines of:

```
varname = new HashMap<Object, FileB>();
```

FileB.java, on the other hand, is defined as such:

```
package com.domain.package;

import stuff;

public class FileB {
    /* global vars */
    public FileB() {
         /* stuff */
    }
}
```

Why am I getting:

```
FileA.java:20: package package does not exist
import package.FileB;
```

? Rather, how do I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because both files are in the same package (`com.domain.package`), you should not need to import `FileB` at all.  You should be able to reference it directly.

Additionally, please ensure that both `FileA` and `FileB` are placed in their package folder: com/domain/package.

Comment: Without that line (import package.FileB;), I get the following errors in terminal: 'FileA.java:23: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class FileB
location: class com.domain.package.FileA
 Map<Object, FileB> varname;
               ^
FileA.java:28: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class FileB
location: class com.domain.package.FileA
  varname = new HashMap<Object, FileB>();
                                  ^'

Comment: If it can't find a file in the same directory, then perhaps the files are not in the proper package folder.  See the addition to my answer.

Comment: Yep, both files are in the directory: .../com/domain/package/

Comment: `javac FileA.java` Edit: I see what you're getting at and thank you. Running `javac FileA.java FileB.java` solves this problem.

Comment: To compile files in packages, go up above the "com" directory, and execute `javac com/domain/package/*.java`.

Answer (score 1):

The package of FileB is `com.domain.package`. You are trying to use `package.FileB` instead.

Comment: Are both files available in the same folder ?

Comment: Both files are in the same directory.

Comment: ok. Have both files been compiled and is their class representation available on the output folder ? Can you see FileA.class and FileB.class ?

Comment: Yes. Both files have be compiled previously.

Comment: Was FileA or FileB ever a non-public class in its lifetime ? I'm trying to explore the possibility that your java and class file representations are out of sync.

Comment: Nope. FileB.java has always been a public class and the definitions for FileA.java were borrowed from a different, working project (aka no, they were never private/protected, etc).

Answer (score 1):

`package` is a [reserved word](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html), don't use it as part of a package name. If you try to add a package with "package" as part of it in Eclipse, you will get an error message:

```
Invalid package name. 'package' is not a valid Java identifier
```

Rename the package, then remove the import statement. You don't need to import a file that's in the same package as the one it's referenced in.

Comment: To clarify, I modified my code to be as general as it could be. `com.domain.package` is a placeholder for a valid package identifier.

Comment: @Tyler: sure. when i post example code my made-up package name is "com.initech.tps". better to pick a valid name to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

@rgettman has the correct solution. Compiling both files using `javac FileA.java FileB.java`solves this issue. You can also use his suggestion: `javac *.java`